# I want to print the numbers present in a string using regularexpressions(regex) IN C++ Language

Tags: regex, c++11

I want to print the numbers present in a string using regularexpressions(regex) IN C++ Language
My code is this, can anybody help me...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<regex>

using namespace std;
void main()
{
    string line="<has id='1235'> 2456 45 83 15 </has>";
    std::regex r("([0-9]+)+");
    cout << line << endl;
    std::smatch m;
    if (regex_search(line , m, r))
    {
       for (auto x:m)
           cout <<x << "\t";
    }
 }
```

I am getting output as :: 1235   5
but i need to get the output :: 1235  2456  45  83  15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match multiple values using [`std::regex_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_iterator):

> `std::regex_iterator` is a read-only [ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator) that accesses the individual matches of a regular expression within the underlying character sequence.

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/kI2CmF):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    std::regex r("[0-9]+");
    std::string line="<has id='1235'> 2456 45 83 15 </has>";
    std::vector<long> vals;
    for(std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), r);
                             i != std::sregex_iterator();
                             ++i)
    {
        std::smatch m = *i;
        vals.push_back(std::stol(m.str()));
    }
    for (auto i: vals)
        std::cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1235
2456
45
83
15
```

Comment: it works, and also i need to store digits in vector(long). can u tell how to store.

Answer (score 0):

Since your numbers are separated, you match them with word boundaries. Use this expression

```
std::regex r("\b([\d]+)\b");
```